# How can I remove a callback added with register_worker_callback()?

Tags: dask, dask-distributed

I have added a custom callback using the client.register_worker_callback() function, now I'd like to remove it.

As part of my pipeline, this process is performed multiple times, intending to register different callback functions at each stage. I would like to remove the previously-registered callback.

Is this possible? So far, the only way I have found is to completely remove and re-add a new scheduler.

I had assumed that re-registering a new callback would over-write the previous callback, but it seems that the worker bootup gets slower with each re-run of register_worker_callback()

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of an easy way today.  Maybe you should raise an issue.